Differential equation with Fourier transform
It is given the following differential equation:
$$-\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} + \frac{dx}{dt} = \theta(t) e^{-\varepsilon t}$$
where $\theta(t)$ is the Heaviside function (which equals $0$ for $t<0$ and equals $1$ for $t\ge 0$) and $\varepsilon$ is a real parameter which is always positive.

Write the equation that the $\tilde{x}=\mathscr{F}[x]$ satisfies and find the most general solution (in the distribution sense).
By anti-transforming, find a solution $x(t)$ to the differential equation, which must satisfy the contour condition of $\lim_{t\to -\infty} x(t) = 0$.
Find the most general solution $x(t)$ which satisfies the previous contour condition.

Note: $\mathscr{F}$ represents the Fourier transform; $\tilde{x}(\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of $x(t)$. Moreover, I will denote distribution associated to a certain function with the function itself.
My solution:
I started by Fourier-transforming the given differential equation to find the equation satisfied by $\tilde{x}(\omega)$. Using the properties of the Fourier transform, I wrote that:
$$- (-i\omega)^2 \tilde{x} (\omega) + (-i\omega)\tilde{x}(\omega) = \mathscr{F}[\theta(t) e^{-\varepsilon t}]$$
To evaluate the F-transform of the right-hand term, I calculated the integral directly:
$$\mathscr{F}[\theta(t) e^{-\varepsilon t}] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \theta(t) e^{i\omega t} e^{-\varepsilon t} \ dt = \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{t(i\omega - \varepsilon)}\ dt=\left[\frac{e^{t(i\omega-\varepsilon)}}{i\omega - \varepsilon}\right]_{0}^{+\infty}=-\frac{1}{i\omega - \varepsilon}$$
Hence:
$$\tilde{x}(\omega) = -\frac{1}{(i\omega-1)(\omega^2-i\omega)}$$
This shouldn't be the most general solution; to obtain that, I either need to anti-transform this, which I don't know how to, or I need to solve the homogeneous differential equation $-x''(t) + x'(t) = 0$ and F-transform to add it to the $\tilde{x}(\omega)$ found above. By doing this, I should get $x(t) = A e^t + B$, with $A$ and $B$ two real constants, but it isn't Fourier-transformable. What am I missing? If you could help me solving my doubts, I'll try to finish it by myself, but if you could provide the entire solution will be much more appreciated; I feel like I need to get more experience with this kind of exercise and, unfortunately, I don't have solutions to this. I'm sorry for having to ask you to solve this problem without even giving you a full solution to this, but I really don't know how to proceed. Thanks in advance for your help, I really appreciate it!
EDIT 1: By using Jordan's lemma to calculate the anti-transform and obtain the particular solution of the differential equation, I get:
$$x_P(t) = \left(\frac{e^{-\varepsilon t} }{\varepsilon (\varepsilon +1)} + \frac{1}{2 \varepsilon } \right) \theta (t) + \left(\frac{e^{t} }{1-i\varepsilon }+\frac{1}{2\varepsilon }\right) \theta (-t)$$
The problem with this is that the contour condition of the second point is never satisfied, which leads me to think that I did something wrong.

Why can't you apply inverse fourier transform and use residue theorem? Namely,
$$x(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{i\omega t}}{\omega(1-i\omega)(\omega-i)},\mathrm d\omega$$

Honestly, I thought I did something wrong because the polynomial at the denominator was strange if compared to those in the exercises I did before. I’ll definitely try this and see if it brings me to the end of the problem. Thank you a lot for the suggestion!

I tried doing that, but as a particular solution I get: $$x_P(t) = \left(\frac{e^{-\varepsilon t} }{\varepsilon (\varepsilon +1)} + \frac{1}{2 \varepsilon } \right) \theta (t) + \left(\frac{e^{t} }{1-i\varepsilon }+\frac{1}{2\varepsilon }\right) \theta (-t)$$ which does not satisfy in any way the question (2). Is there something wrong with this?

Well, you were on the right track.  But we need to ensure that $x(t)$ has a Fourier Transform.  Let's start from the ODE
$$-x''+x'=\theta(t)e^{-\varepsilon t}\tag1$$
and impose the additional condition that $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty}x(t)=0$.  This will be the particular solution to $(1)$.
Now let the Fourier Transform, $\tilde{x}(\omega)$, of the $L^1$ function, $x(t)$, be defined as
$$\tilde{x}(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t)e^{i\omega t}\,dt\tag2$$
Applying $(2)$ to $(1)$, we find that
$$\omega(\omega-i)\tilde{x}(\omega)=\frac1{\varepsilon - i \omega}\tag3$$
Solving $(3)$ for $\tilde{x}(\omega)$ yields
$$\tilde{x}(\omega)=\frac{i}{\omega(\omega-i)(\omega+i\varepsilon)}\tag4$$
provided that $\omega\ne 0$ and $\omega\ne i$.  In fact, note that in general, $\omega(\omega-i)\left(\tilde{x}(\omega)+A\delta(\omega)\right)=\frac1{\varepsilon -i\omega}$.  But, inasmuch as $x(\pm \infty)=0$, the constant $A$ must be equal to $0$.
Next, we find $x(t)$ by applying the Inverse Fourier Transform to $(4)$.  To do so, we must interpret the Inverse Fourier Transform as a Principal Value integral due to the pole at $\omega=0$.  Therefore, we can write
$$\begin{align}
x(t)&=\mathscr{F^{-1}}\{\tilde{x}\}(t)\\\\
&=\frac1{2\pi}\,\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \tilde{x}(\omega)e^{-i\omega t}\,d\omega\\\\
&=\frac1{2\pi}\lim_{\delta\to 0^+}\int_{|\omega|\ge \delta}\tilde{x}(\omega)e^{-i\omega t}\,d\omega\tag5
\end{align}$$
Now, we evaluate $(5)$ using the Resiude Theorem.  For $t<0$, we close the contour in the upper-half plane with a semi-circular deformation with radius $\delta$ around $\omega=0$.  Proceeding, we have
$$\begin{align}
x(t)&= i \text{Res}\left(\tilde{x}(\omega)e^{-i\omega t}, \omega=i\right)+\frac i2 \text{Res}\left(\tilde{x}(\omega), \omega=0\right)\\\\
&=\frac{e^{t}}{1+\varepsilon}-\frac{1}{2\varepsilon} \tag6
\end{align}$$
For $t>0$, we close the contour in the upper-half plane with a semi-circular deformation with radius $\delta$ around $\omega=0$.  Proceeding, we have
$$\begin{align}
x(t)&= i \text{Res}\left(\tilde{x}(\omega), \omega=i\right)+\frac i2 \text{Res}\left(\tilde{x}(\omega), \omega=0\right)\\\\
&=-\frac{e^{-\varepsilon t}}{\varepsilon(1+\varepsilon)}+\frac{1}{2\varepsilon} \tag7
\end{align}$$
Finally, using $(6)$ and $(7)$ together, we can write
$$x(t)=\frac1{2\varepsilon}\text{sgn}(t)+\frac1{1+\varepsilon}\left(e^t\theta(-t)-\frac1\varepsilon e^{-\varepsilon t}\theta(t)\right)\tag8$$
Let's verify that $(8)$ is a solution to $(1)$.  Differentiating twice reveals that
$$\begin{align}
x'(t)&=\frac1\varepsilon \delta(t)+\frac1{1+\varepsilon}\left(-\frac{1+\varepsilon}{\varepsilon}\delta(t)+e^t\theta(-t)+ e^{-\varepsilon t}\theta(t)\right)\\\\
x''(t)&=\frac1\varepsilon \delta'(t)+\frac1{1+\varepsilon}\left(-\frac{1+\varepsilon}{\varepsilon}\delta'(t)\right)\\\\
&+\frac1{1+\varepsilon}\left(-\delta(t)+\delta(t)\right)\\\\
&+\frac1{1+\varepsilon}\left(e^t\theta(-t)-\varepsilon e^{-\varepsilon t}\theta(t)\right)
\end{align}$$
Subtracting $x''(t)$ from $x'(t)$ yields $e^{-\varepsilon t}\theta(t)$ as was to be shown.
Note that the general solution includes the homogeneous terms $Ae^{t}+B$.

Thank you a lot for taking time to write this detailed solution. It was very much appreciated!

You're quite welcome.   It was my pleasure.
